# Webslides: Change position, opacity and style of the navigation arrows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am fairly new to HTML, CSS and a beginner in Javascript.

Webslides is a great tool for making slides but my feedback from users was that it wasn't obvious that a user is landing on a webslides. I would like to address this by changing the position of the arrow keys to the center left and center right of the screen, to change the opacity and possibly size and style of the arrow keys, maybe something like [this](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/430575/arrow_arrows_direction_navigation_right_right_arrow_icon)

How do I go about doing this? I am assuming that this is produced by javascript but I cannot find anything obvious to change. Any suggestinos, however vague, would be greatly appreciated so that I know what to work towards.

Comment: Can you show what you already have, and what change you want in that ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to make the icon out of pure CSS, using multiple elements and border radius and other rules. You can read more about making shapes in CSS [here](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/).